# How do I migrate data from a local to a remote MySQL instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-migration

I have a local MySQL database and I want to migrate the data inside of it to a remote MySQL database (using RDS on AWS). How can I migrate my data between the two instances?

Comment: Fix grammatical errors and better explain the intent of the question

Answer (score 0):

> AWS DMS helps you migrate large, terabyte-scale databases to the AWS
>   Cloud easily and securely. During migration, the source database
>   remains fully operational, minimizing downtime.

But judging form your question you want homogeneous data migration and as per AWS Documentation:

> If you're performing a homogeneous migration, use your engine’s native
>   tools, such as MySQL dump or MySQL replication.

Refer to [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database) for using SQL Dump on larger data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use AWS database migration service that is available in Aws. You need to provide your database end-point I,e your on premises data- base server end-point in it and also set your db engine parameters to your requirement and launch. it talks 10-15 minutes to migrate your data to cloud and from there you can continue accessing your database from the AWS it self.

The other method is, take a recent back up of your on premises database. Launch an instance in aws EC2 and install the db that you are using on premises.copy the back file in your system to cloud.using the backup file available launch the database.set up an RDS instance of the type that you have installed in EC2, and connect the end points.